# Working principle of simple chemical cells

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

I have just learnt about simple chemical cells but I have no idea how to determine which cells will work and which will not and the working principle of those cells.

I know that a chemical cell with $\ce{Zn}$ and $\ce{Cu}$ as electrodes and $\ce{CuSO4}$ as electrolyte will create a current in the external circuit. But why would $\ce{Zn}$ choose to lose electrons through the external circuit instead of having displacement reaction with the $\ce{CuSO4}$ electrolyte directly? And in the following cases, which of the cells will work and which will not?

```
    Electrodes   Electrolyte

1   Zn, Cu       ZnSO4

2   Zn, C        CuSO4

3   C, Cu        CuSO4

4   C, Cu        ZnSO4
```

And why do they (not) give out a current? Does it depend on the location of the elements in the electrochemical series? Does the choice of electrolyte affect the cells in any way?

Thank you.

### Update

After reading several related questions, I find some contradictions between the answers. Is there a strict rule to decide which electrolyte to use or is it fine to use anything as long as it has good conductivity and does not react quickly with the electrodes?

[Does it matter what electrolyte we use for a Galvanic Cell?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75086/does-it-matter-what-electrolyte-we-use-for-a-galvanic-cell?rq=1)

[What is the Purpose of an Electrolyte in a Galvanic Cell?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44469/what-is-the-purpose-of-an-electrolyte-in-a-galvanic-cell?rq=1)

Comment: Zn will react with CuSO4 directly all right, because it can. At the same time it would continue losing electrons via the external circuit, for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

in simple cells the oxidation,reduction reaction happens automatically so it depends on the location of the element in the electrochemical series 
......the elements with a higher oxidation number in the top have more ability to lose electrons and and become a positive ion and this ability goes down when you go down the series ......
for ex.   E°(oxidation of Zn ) > E°(oxidation of Cu) 
so the Zn loses 2e turning into Zn+2 .....
Cu+2 take these 2e and turn into cu
.....
the electrolyte for sure affect the cell because it contains the ions of the cathode's element (Cu2+) that will be replaced by the onee from anode (Zn+2) as I mentioned before 
yet i'm not sure if that's what you want to know :)

Comment: Thanks! But for cells that have Zn and C as electrodes, I believe that C cannot take the electrons from Zn. Then would the cell not give out a current or would the electrolyte take part in the redox reaction in some way?

Comment: well.. I think that zn will give the 2e directly to the cu2+ ions in the electrolyte so cooper will deposit on the Zn electrode it's like when you but a piece of Zn in the electrolyte CuSO4 and im not sure about the role of C that's why I didn't answer this part of you Question